# How do I Restricts Commands to Certain Roles?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

So, I am trying to make a bot and there is a certain command in which I only want some staff roles to be able to use. (The rest will get some kind of error message or something). This is the code I have so far:

```
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`**Hello there! Thank you for opening a ticket today. I am ${message.author} with United Servers™. How may I assist you today?**`)
    .setThumbnail("")
    .setColor("BLACK")
    message.channel.send(embed)
    message.delete({ timeout: 1 })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to perform the necessary checks and error handling based on the author of the message.

The Message object has an 'member' parameter of type GuildMember. You can check the membership of this user in the different roles in the guild. Based on these membership checks you can customize the behaviour.

Something like this

```
if(message.member.roles.cache.has(your role here)) {
//do something
}else{
//do something else
}
```